# How should I "yield" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am a bit new to modern JavaScript (ES8). What is a preferred way to yield asynchronously, i.e. continue script execution upon some future iterations of the event loop, using `await`? I saw the following options:

```
async function yield1() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  console.log("done");
}

async function yield2() {
  // setImmediate is non-standard, only Edge and Node have it
  await new Promise(done => (setImmediate? setImmediate: setTimeout)(done));
  console.log("done");
}

async function yield3() {
  await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done));
  console.log("done");
}
```

Should I chose one after another or they're all the same? Or maybe it depends on the environment (node, browser)?

---

*Updated*, was asked in the comments about what I'm trying to achieve. It is a simple observable object that asynchronously fires `propertyChanged` event when its properties change. Here is a full example, and the "yielding" piece is inside `firePropertyChanged`:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Model extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(data) {
    super();
    this._data = data;
  }

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }

  set data(newValue) {
    const oldValue = this._data;
    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
      this._data = newValue;
      this.firePropertyChanged('data', newValue, oldValue);
    }
  }

  async firePropertyChanged(property, newValue, oldValue) {
    await Promise.resolve().then(() =>
      super.emit('propertyChanged', { target: this, property, newValue, oldValue }));
    console.log('all propertyChanged handlers have been called asynchronously');
  }
}

async function waitForChange(obj) {
  await new Promise(resolve => 
    obj.once('propertyChanged', args => 
      console.log(`propertyChanged: ${args.property}, ${args.oldValue} -> ${args.newValue}`)));
}

async function test() {
  const obj = new Model("old");
  var change = waitForChange(obj);
  console.log(`before change: ${obj.data}`);
  obj.data = "new";
  console.log(`after change: ${obj.data}`);
  await change;
}

test().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

If you run it with node, the expected output should be:

```
before change: old
after change: new
propertyChanged: data, old -> new
all propertyChanged handlers have been called asynchronously
```

The order of this output matters, i.e., I don't want any event handlers for `propertyChanged` to be invoked before the setter method for `data` has returned to the caller.

Comment: Are you aware that `setImmediate` is not standardised?  You might want to discount that one because of that in itself.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, no I'm not, thanks for pointing out. It seems to be working across all modern browsers and Node though (IE11 is out of the question).

Comment: Interesting - the MDN is listing it as [mostly not implemented across the board](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: rxjs is a reactive js library. you can create observables which will feel familiar to using generators in say, python. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: @JamesThorpe, you're right! Only Edge and Node have `setImmediate`. That leaves me with only #1 and #3.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Can you show us an example of where you'r'e trying to use this and what you're trying to do with it in that example?  Javascript doesn't generally think of the  concept of "yielding".  You initiate an asynchronous operation, then return control back to the event loop.  When the asynchronous operation completes, you resume your logic flow in the completion callback.  This can also be done with promises and `await`.

Comment: @jfriend00, I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: Are you just asking "how do you execute a piece of code on a future turn of the event loop so that any other code in this turn of the loop finishes before you execute this next piece of code"?  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Also, if that's the case (that you just want to run something after the current trun of the event loop finishes executing), then there are multiple ways to do that and which you choose depends upon what else you want to run before your next code (where you want to get in line).  Any particular preferences on that?  Do you want it to get in line at the front of the queue, end of the queue, before any pending I/O events, after and pending I/O events?

Comment: @jfriend00, yes I want to run a piece of code on a future iteration of the event loop in the most efficient way (and let the current method return). No particular preferences, but but the order of continuations should matter. E.g., in my example, if `property1` changed, then `property2` changed,  I first want `propertyChanged` be fired for `property1`, then for `property2` (in both cases, asynchronously to the code that changed both properties). I hope it makes sense, thanks for following up with me on this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I'll address the new summary of your question in your comments (you should probably edit your question to just say this):

> I want to run a piece of code on a future iteration of the event loop in the most efficient way (and let the current method return). No particular preferences, but but the order of continuations should matter. E.g., in my example, if property1 changed, then property2 changed, I first want propertyChanged be fired for property1, then for property2 (in both cases, asynchronously to the code that changed both properties).

The short version is you can use pretty much any of the options below to solve your issue.  Without knowing more about your specific situations/requirements, I would probably recommend `setImmediate()` because it can't starve the event queue if triggered recursively, but either `process.nextTick()` or `Promise.resolve().then()` will trigger sooner (before other types of events) if that matters to your caller.

Here's some explanation of each choice - each will likely fulfill your objective, but each differs in some details.

All of these options allow the current tick of the event loop to finish and then they schedule a callback to be called on a future tick of the event loop.  They differ in exactly when the next callback will be called and some will vary when they schedule the next callback based upon what type of event is currently be processed (e.g. where the event loop is in it's process of scanning several different event queues).

You can start by reading this overview article [The Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

**process.nextTick(cb)**

This is the soonest way to schedule the callback.  The current tick of the event loop finishes its execution and then before the node.js event loop code looks at any other event queues in the event loop, it looks for items in the `nextTickQueue` and runs them.  Note, it is possible to "starve" the event loop if you are continually calling `process.nextTick()` recursively because it does not give other events a chance to run until the `nextTickQueue` is empty.  This is not a "fair" scheduler.

[image]

**setImmediate(cb)**

This schedules a callback to be run after the current "phase" of the event loop is finished.  You can think of the event loop as cycling through a number of different types of queues.  When the current type of queue that is being processed is empty, then any pending `setImmediate()` callbacks will get processed.

Note, how this relates to other types of events, then depends upon what type of event was processing when `setImmediate()` was called.

As an example, if you were in the completion callback from `fs.read()` and you called `setImmediate()` to schedule a callback, then the event loop would first process any other pending I/O events before processing your `setImmediate()` callback.  Because it doesn't get called until the event loop advances to the next type of event in the event queue, you can't starve the event loop with `setImmediate()`.  Even recursively call `setImmediate()` will still cycle through all events.

How a pending `setTimeout()` is processed relative to a `setImmediate()` that you schedule depends upon what phase of the event loop you were in when you called the `setImmediate()`.   This is generally beyond the scope of what you should be aware of in your code.  If relative timing of multiple async operations like this is important, then you are much safer to just write code that guarantees a given sequence regardless of exactly when they operation is enabled by its callback.  Promises can help you sequence things like this.

**setTimeout(cb, 0)**

Timers are one phase of the event loop.  As it goes around the event loop looking at different types of event queues, one of the stages is to look for any timer events whose time has passed and thus it is time to call their callback.  Because of this timers only run when the event loop is in the "timer phase" so how they fire relative to other types of events is indeterminate.  It depends upon where the event loop is in its cycle when the timer is ready to go.  Personally, I generally don't use `setTimeout(cb, 0)` unless I'm trying to synchronize with other timer events as this will guarantee a FIFO order with other timer events, but not with other types of events.

**Promise.resolve().then(cb)**

To get to this level of detail for promises (which you normally don't need to), you have to be very aware of what the promise implementation you are using is and how it works.  A non-native-code promise implementation will use one of the other timing mechanisms to schedule its `.then()` handlers.  Any of them can appropriately meet the Promise specification so they can vary.

Native promises in node.js do have a specific implementation.  Personally, I know of no reason why you should write code that depends upon this specific implementation, but lots of people seem to be curious so I'll explain.

You can see a good diagram in this article: [Promises, nextTicks and setImmediates](https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa).  Native promises are implemented using what's called a micro tasks queue.  It's essentially another queue like the nextTick queue that is processed after the `nextTickQueue`, but before any of the other queues.  So, queued up `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers run immediately after and `nextTick` calls that are already scheduled and before any other types of events (timers, I/O completion, etc...).

[image]

Non-native promise implementations (like Bluebird or Q) don't have the ability to make a new microTasks queue that is processed after the nextTick queue so they use `setImmediate()` or `process.nextTick()`.